# Casting Results from Generic Method Invocation?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm currently messing about with generics and I'm trying to write a function that I can call to load everything from a database table simply by specifying the table name.

I'm most of the way there; my generic methods all seem to work, but I'm not quite sure how to cast my results into something usable.

This is the guts of the method so far:

```
private static List<EntityCodeBase> GetCodeLoadResults(CodeTables table)
{
    List<EntityCodeBase> results = new List<EntityCodeBase>();
    Assembly assm = Assembly.Load(new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("RR"));
    Type tableType = assm.GetTypes().Where(u => u.Name.ToLower() == table.ToString().ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
    MethodInfo mi = typeof(SpecificEntity).GetMethod("LoadAll");

    mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(tableType);
    mi.Invoke(null, null); //how can I cast the resulting object into a List<EntityCodeBase> ?

    return results;
}
```

Comment: So what does the method you're invoking *actually* return?  Also, this is generally a task for which generics are not all that well suited for.  If you just want to learn about generics, there are much better tasks to attempt.  Solving this particular problem often involves "hacks" that would otherwise be discouraged.

Comment: If this is all your code, wont `RR.Users.LoadAll()` (assuming there is a table called users) be cleaner than using reflection? You still need to cast it to the concrete type to be usable.

Comment: @Servy - It returns a list of objects that inherit from EntityCodeBase.  So in my running code, the invocation is returning a List<JobTypeCode>.  But it could just as easily be a List<PeriodCode> depending on how I call it.

Comment: @SWeko - I agree.  This is academic though.  I wanted to see if I could create a generic function that could fill this gap instead of having to write several dozen LoadAll() methods.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `SpecificEntity.LoadAll` returns a list of some type derived from `EntityCodeBase`, you can't cast directly to a `List<EntityCodeBase>` but you can cast to `IEnumerable<EntityCodeBase>`. Then you can create a new list:

```
var ecbList = (IEnumerable<EntityCodeBase>)mi.Invoke(null, null);
return list.ToList();
```

It might be cleaner however, if you can get the table name from the entity type, either directly by name, using attributes, or using a map. Then you can make `GetCodeLoadResults` generic in the result type e.g.

```
private static List<T> GetCodeLoadResults() where T : EntityCodeBase
{
    Assembly assm = Assembly.Load(new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("RR"));
    Type tableType = //get table type from T
    MethodInfo mi = typeof(SpecificEntity).GetMethod("LoadAll");

    mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(tableType);
    return (List<T>)mi.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

If you're not using .Net 4, you can't cast a `List<TDerived>` to an `IEnumerable<TBase>`, so you'll have to cast to `IEnumerable` first:

```
return ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)mi.Invoke(null, null))
    .Cast<EntityCodeBase>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting this when I try that change:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RR.Entities.JobPreferenceTypeCode]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RR.Core.EntityCodeBase]'.

Comment: @SonnyBoy - Is `RR.Entities.JobPreferenceTypeCode` a subtype of `RR.Core.EntityCodeBase`? If you're using .Net 4, it should work in that case, if you're using 3.5 you'll have to cast to `IEnumerable` and use the `Cast<T>` method.

Comment: Yes, it is a subtype.  And I am on .NET 3.5.

I tried the cast to IEnumerable and it now works.

Code now looks like this:
'results = ((IEnumerable)mi.Invoke(null, null)).Cast<EntityCodeBase>().ToList();'

Thank you very much!